# How to handle fallback issues in vue.js?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, fallback

I am working on the project by linking vue2 and spring boot.

When I built vue and ran spring boot, I got the following error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcBsI.png)

```
@Controller
public class WebErrorController implements ErrorController{

    @GetMapping({"/","/error"})
    public String redirctRoot() {
        return "index.html";
    }
    
}
```

So I solved it using ErrorController in spring boot.

But I was asked to deal with this error in the vue2.

How to handle fallback issues in vue.js?

I tried navigation guard but it didnt pass this code

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log('before');
  console.log(to);
  console.log(from);
  next()
})

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Do you have a '/error' route defined?